# Cant get to work passing dropdown value to a text box using if else condition (Javascript HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

I was creating an incident notification generator using HTML with local storage javascript however as I was new to programming and started learning through YouTube I can't make it to work.

I have textbox that should display the description of the issue which is based on the dropdown selection(business impact, affected  and affected feature)

If BIZimpact is Partial
Textbox = we are investigating an outage (Dropdown - Affected Features) + (Dropdown - Affected City)

If BIZimpact is FULL
Textbox = We are experiencing a system outage

Textbox (Incident Description ) should go here

Please help me

```html
<body>
      <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Business Impact</label>
                            <select id="bizimpact" required>
                                <option disabled selected>Select impact</option>
                                <option value="Partial">Partial</option>
                                <option value="Full">Full</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

   <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Feature Selected</label>
                            <select id=“featureSelect” required>
                                <option disabled selected>Select impact</option>
                                <option value=“Ordering”>Ordering</option>
                                <option value=“Delivery”>Delivery Dispatch</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>


   <div class="input-field">
                            <label>City</label>
                            <select id=“affectedCity” required>
                                <option disabled selected>Select impact</option>
                                <option value=“Colorado”>Colorado</option>
                                <option value=“Mayabig”>Mayabig</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

var selectbizimpact = document.getElementById('bizimpact').value;
var selectfeatselect = document.getElementById('featureSelect').value;
 var selectaffectedcity = document.getElementById(‘affectedCity).value;

var resultext = '';
                    
resultext += document.getElementById(‘featureSelect').value + ' . A subset of users may face an issue ';
resultext += document.getElementById(‘affectedcity').value + ' due to system technical difficulties. Concerned support teams is currently working to restore normal performance levels. 


   localStorage.setItem("featureSelectvalue", selectfeatselect);
   localStorage.setItem("affectedcityvalue", selectaffectedcity);
   localStorage.setItem("resultext", resultext);

 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("resultext");



If biz impact = FULL

Result = We are investigating a full system outage

If bizimpact = PARTIAL
Result = we are investigating a degraded system performance affecting [order / Delivery] in the city of [Colorado / Mayabig]…etc
```

Comment: Please add your code otherwise this question will probably be closed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, have added the code part. please assist

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet shows a frivolous snippet that shows how you can use the selected value from a `select` menu in an event handler to perform a lookup of pre-defined key/values. This, I feel, is applicable to how I have interpreted your question or the requirements therein.

```js
const matrix={
  'low':'Bananas make lousy pets',
  'medium':'Spacebats have taken up residence',
  'standard':'The Hampsters have run out of milk',
  'serious':'A wombat ate my cat',
  'critical':'Crayfish are living in my socks'
}

const d=document;
const oSelect=d.querySelector('[name="issue"]');
const oText=d.querySelector('[name="description"]');

Object.keys( matrix ).forEach( key=>{
  oSelect.appendChild( new Option( key, key ) )
});
oSelect.addEventListener('change',function(e){
  oText.value=this.options.selectedIndex > 0 ? matrix[this.value] : ''
});
```

```css
select,
[type='text']{width:80%;padding:1rem;margin:0.5rem;}

select option:nth-of-type(1){
  background:pink
}
```

```html
<select name='issue'>
  <option>Select Issue
</select>
<input type='text' name='description'>
```

A not so trivial/frivolous, more appropriate example which does what I think you are hoping to do which ties in `localStorage` to maintain state of the menus. Copy in it's entirety and save to test functionality - snippets will not work here with local/session Storage!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .input-field {
                margin: 1rem;
                padding: 1rem;
                font-family: monospace;
                width:80%;
                border:1px dotted grey;
                min-height:3rem;
                line-height:3rem;
            }

            label {
                display: block;
                width: 80%;
            }

            select {
                padding: 1rem;
                float: right;
                width: 60%;
            }

            [type='text'],
                textarea{
                padding:1rem;
                width:80%;
                margin:1rem;
                width:80%;
                resize:none;
            }

            .partial{
                background:gold;
            }
            .full{
                background:rgba(255,0,0,0.55);
                color:white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='input-field'>
            <label>Business Impact
                <select name='bizimpact' class='bizselect' required>
                    <option disabled selected>Select impact
                    <option>Partial
                    <option>Full
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class='input-field'>
            <label>Feature Selected
                <select name='featureSelect' class='bizselect' required>
                    <option disabled selected>Select impact
                    <option>Ordering
                    <option>Delivery Dispatch
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class='input-field'>
            <label>City
                <select name='affectedCity' class='bizselect' required>
                    <option disabled selected>Select impact
                    <option>Colorado
                    <option>Mayabig
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>


        <textarea name='message' cols=80 rows=5></textarea>
        <script>
            // utility/shorthand methods
            const d=document;
            const q=(e,n=d)=>n.querySelector(e);
            const qa=(e,n=d)=>n.querySelectorAll(e);
            
            // select menu value lookup matrix
            const matrix={
              'Partial': 'We are investigating an outage with',
              'Full': 'We are experiencing a system outage with',
              'featureSelect':'A subset of users may face an issue',
              'affectedCity':'due to system technical difficulties. Concerned support teams are currently working to restore normal performance levels.'
            };
            
            // the name of the store in localStorage
            const _STORENAME='BusinessImpact';
            
            // nodelist of all select menus
            const colSelect=qa('select');
            // variable( object literal ) used to track which select menus have been changed
            const selection={};


            // function to gather values from select menus - perform lookups into matrix
            const setmessage=()=>{
                let args=[];
                    args.push( matrix[ q('select[name="bizimpact"]').value ] );
                    args.push( `"${q('select[name="featureSelect"]').value}"` );
                    args.push( matrix.featureSelect );
                    args.push( `"${q('select[name="affectedCity"]').value}"` );
                    args.push( matrix.affectedCity );
                    
                // display the message and set the css className
                q('textarea[name="message"]').value=args.join(' ');
                q('textarea[name="message"]').className=q('select[name="bizimpact"]').value.toLowerCase();
            };
            
            
            
            
            const changehandler=(e)=>{
              // add key/value pair to keep track of select elements that have been populated.
              selection[ e.target.name ]=e.target.value;
              
              // if not all select menus are populated, stop.
              if( Object.keys( selection ).length!==colSelect.length ) return;
              
              // display the message
              setmessage();
              
              // save in localStorage the values held for selected menus
              localStorage.setItem( _STORENAME, JSON.stringify( selection ) );
            };


            // rebuild menus with values stored in localStorage
            d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',(e)=>{
              if( localStorage.getItem( _STORENAME )!=null ){
                let json=JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( _STORENAME ) );
                
                Object.keys( json ).forEach(k=>{
                  // set the value of the select menu
                  q(`select[ name="${k}" ]`).value=json[k];
                  
                  // repopulate the `selection` variable !! 
                  selection[k]=json[k];
                });
                
                // display the message.
                setmessage()
              }
            });


            // delegated change event handler bound to the document and delegating to `select` menus.
            d.addEventListener('change',(e)=>{
              if( e.target.className=='bizselect' ){
                changehandler.call(this,e);
              }
            });
            
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks master @Professor Abronsius....changing the message content based on dropdown selection is correct. Would it be possible if the notification message and drop down menus (as static)  can be  passed to another html instead. thanks for your assistance

Comment: yes of course-there are at least 3 ways (off the top of my head) in which that can be done

Comment: master @Professor Abronsius if its not too much to ask can you please share code for localstorage implementation wherein after selecting all the input from the first page, selected values will be presented on the 2nd html page

Comment: If this "2nd HTML page" is opened in the same browser you can use one of the messaging functions within Javascript ( such as [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API), [Channel Messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Channel_Messaging_API) etc ) but if the other (2nd/3rd...) HTML page is opened by a different browser / computer you will need another technology/approach - perhaps a websocket. I feel however that this additional requirement has fundamentally altered the scope of the original question